# Correct usage of up to / by

Tags: word-choice

Which one is a correct and effective way of giving someone a compliment.

Jon helped us scale our business up to 40%

OR

he helped us scale our business by 40%

Are both phrases correct? If yes then which one is more effective/convincing?

Comment: They mean totally different things. And which is more effective is a matter of opinion.

Comment: As Jason Bassford suggests, "scale our business [by] up to 40%" and "scale [up] our business by 40%" have very different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The first is meaningless without context.  "Up to 40%" implies that there is an absolute scale.  You might say something like, "we saw business up to 40% *more than* last year's sales by the first quarter".  This way you are comparing it to something specific which is 100%, but there needs to be an explicit reference to the context.
The second already implies a reference to past performance.  So "up 40%" means that you did 40% better than the last performance period.